# Semi-circle inside of a square

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

We have a square **ABCD**, and a semi-circle inside it with **AB** as its base. We make a tangent line from point **C** different from **CB** and mark its point of contact with the semi-circle **F**. Then we mark the intersection of **BD** with the semi-circle (different from point **B**) point **E**.

What's the area of triangle **BEF** if AB=10?

[image]

Comment: Sure that there is a more elegant solution, but you can find the coordinates of the vertices and use Heron's formula.

Comment: As they say ... *What have you tried?* and *Where did you get stuck?* ... This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) telling you things you already know or talking over your head. (And it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3448796/edit) to add your thoughts.

Comment: Note that CBSF is cyclic and SF is hence parallel to BE

Comment: @EdwardH. $CBSF$ is indeed cyclic, but $SF$ is not parallel to $BE$. $SF$ is perpendicular to $CX$ (the tangent to the semicircle at $F$) and $CX$ is clearly not perpendicular to $BE$.

Comment: @nickgard Right. I thought X=A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's extremely fast if you just use Pythagoras and similarities. Here's how.

[image]

1. Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle COB$ gives $\overline{CO} = 5\sqrt{5}$.
2. Similarity $\triangle COB \sim \triangle OBH$ yields $\overline{OH} = \sqrt 5$, and $\overline{FB} = 2\overline{BH}= 4\sqrt 5$.
3. Similarity $\triangle OBH \sim \triangle FBP$ gives $\overline{FP} = 4$ and $\overline{PB} = 8$.

Now it is straightforward to calculate the required area by means of successive subtractions from the area of rectangle $PBRQ$:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal A_{FBE} &=& \mathcal A_{PBRQ}-\mathcal A_{FBP}-\mathcal A_{EBR}-\mathcal A_{FEQ}=\\
&=&40-16-\frac{25}2-\frac32=10.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

I'll skip the calculations because they're probably ugly in a non-informative way.

You know $BC=FC=10$ and $BS=SF=5$.  You can then find $CS$ with the Pythagorean theorem.  $BCFS$ is a cyclic quadrilateral (since it has opposite right angles), so you can find $BF$ by Ptolemy's theorem.

Now you can work out $m\angle CBF$ and $m\angle BSF$ with the law of cosines.  $m\angle EBF=m\angle CNF-45^\circ$ and $m\angle BEF$ is the supplement of half of $m\angle BSF$ because it is an inscribed angle that subtends the same chord as $\angle BSF$.

Now that you have two angles and a non-included side of the desired triangle, you can just bang the rest of it out using the law of sines and the fact that the area of a triangle is half the product of two sides and the sine of the angle between them.

Answer (score 2):

Non-trigonometric solution: Let $S(0,0)$, $B(r,0)$, $C(r,2r)$ and $E(0,r)$.  The line $p$ through $BF$ is the polare of the semi-circle from $C$, hence its equation is 
$$p\colon x\cdot r+y\cdot2r=r^2\iff x=r-2y.$$
From here $F(-\frac35r,\frac45r)$ is easily derived. Call $G(-\frac35,0)$ the foot of the dropped perpendicular from $F$ on $AB$.

Now sum (as usual) the area of the trapezoid $GSEF$ and the triangle $SBE$ and subtract the area of triangle $GBF$ to arrive in $\frac25r^2$.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for my misunderstanding about posting the solution with external hyperlinks. Since images are acceptable, I divided the solution into 3 different images. Is that acceptable? Or do I need to type it.

[Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtuu5.jpg)
[Solution part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHm1K.jpg)
[Solution part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEpTD.jpg)

Thanks,
R. de Souza